# Writing to a Csv with Quotation Marks Present

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, write.table

I am running into an issue when using `write.table()`. I am writing a dataframe to a csv, and any time a column has a " quotation mark in it, the data is not writing how I'd like.

I am trying to write this dataframe to a csv:

```
activity          date         status
widen table by 5" 01-05-2022     Y
router holes      01-25-2022     G
cut wood          02-03-2022     R
```

The activity in the first row is writing strangely for me. When I write it to a csv, it appears as:

```
activity               date         status
widen table by 5\",P" 01-05-2022     Y
router holes          01-25-2022     G
cut wood              02-03-2022     R
```

This is the code I am using to write to a csv:

```
write.table(df, "df.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = !file.exists("df.csv"), 
append = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to use `write.csv` instead of `write.table`.

```
write.csv(df, "df.csv",  row.names = F)
```

But if you really want to use `write.table`, you need to specify `qmethod="double"`.

```
write.table(df, "df.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, 
    col.names = T, append = T, qmethod="double")
```